# UTF-8 encoding in a v-for

Tags: vue.js

i'm trying to list all product from my databse. All my page is display well but for my list the UTF-8 encoding doesn't seems to work. I'm french so i use some "é è ê"..
So when i'm doing something like
    `<div class ="notrelevent"> Général </div>`

it works great but when i do something like

```
`<tr v-for="product in products | paginate" :product="product"></tr>    `
```

I have bad result like : this is a test � again cr�me

Or i should get :

this is a test à again crème

Thanks for the help

Comment: seems to be more of a databse problem. How to you select the stuff from the database. How are the tables + the db encoded? What happens when outputting the db results directly?

Comment: @FrankProvost i tried several think for my databse i found on inernet, but nothing seems to work. When outputting the db result directly in terminal i'v got the � and when i output in in browser i'v got \ufffd .

Answer (score 3):

1) In your HTML  section, you should put this:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

2) Any database call should be done with a client using utf8.

Comment: Making sure the web server is actually sending the HTML content with utf-8 charset (instead of for example a default iso-8859-1) is also important.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in Notepad++, go to "Encoding" -> "Convert to UTF-8" and then save the file, and problem solved